# Use @RequestBody to receive data from ajax and binding it to 'User', but failed

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc, data-binding

I used AJAX to submit data to the spring boot backend with the `@RequestBody` annotation to accept it. However, when doing that, it showed the followinng error, which confuses me:

> Required String parameter 'username' is not present

**Console output**

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]
```

**AJAX code**

```
$("#submitBTN").click(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            async:false,
            url:"/user/doSignIn?verification="+$("input[name='verificationCode']").val(),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",//必须加
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'username': $("input[name='username']").val(),
                'password':$("input[name='password']").val(),
                'email': $("input[name='email']").val()
            }),
            success:function(r){
                if(r.code==window.ResponseStatus.OK){
                    $(window).attr('location',+'/index');
                }else{
                    console.log(r.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**Entity User**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    // 自增id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    // 用户名
    @Pattern(regexp = "^.{4,14}$",groups = UserSignUp.class)
    @Column(length = 14)
    private String username;
    // 密码
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*.]{6,25}$")
    @Column(length = 25)
    private String password;
    // 邮箱
    @Email
    private String email;
    // 电话号码
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{11}$",groups = UserSignUp.class)
    @Column(length = 11)
    private String phoneNumber;
    // 所属用户组
    private byte userGroup;
```

**RequestHandler code**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/doSignUp")
public FOResponse doSignUp(@RequestBody User user,
                           BindingResult result,
                           @RequestParam String verificationCode,
                           HttpSession session){...}
```

Comment: can you show us the values and also make sure that you made the setter for username not only getter in User class

Comment: I just found out the cause of the mistake.the url in ajax not equals  the value of @PostMapping. Thanks  for your  enthusiastic answer.

Comment: Your Ajax says ‘doSignIn’ but your Controller is expecting ‘doSignUp’. Also, in the Ajax remove the single quotes on the object keys.